# Make an app impossible to quit

Tags: macos, bash, exit, osx-elcapitan

I want to make an app I have impossible to quit by normal means, only by forcequitting. Is this possible? (I do  have limited knowledge of bash)

I use MacOSX ElCapitan. Thank you in advance for the help!

Edit: To clarify, I want it not to be able to quit with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> or by rightclicking the app and pressing quit, or quitting through the App menu on the top bar.

Answer (score -1):

You could intercept any control-c type signals with a signal handler.
Here is an example:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap "echo 'Caught Signal'" SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM
while true; do
    echo "looping"
    sleep 5
done
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how to do a signal handler. How can I factor in the app itself?

Comment: This is only relevant to a shell script, not a general OS X app.

Comment: Its tagged as a bash problem.  So I answered it as a bash problem.